# Camel-groovy - Route Transaction and rollback containing cxf endpoint

Tags: web-services, maven, groovy, transactions, apache-camel

Im new to Apache camel - groovy, maven projects.

I am trying to create a route like this

```
from("file://E://Target//JVNumber")
        .transacted("PROPAGATION_REQUIRED")
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .setHeader("operationName",simple("updateJVNumber"))
        .to("cxf:bean:webservice-ws?dataFormat=PAYLOAD")
        .markRollbackOnly()
        .log('${body}');
```

The Webservice request succeeds and sends the response. But since the whole route contains a rollback call, I want to rollback the cxf request lastly sent also. Could How someone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rollback is only for the transaction status, and the transaction manager can only rollback resources which native supports transaction. Such resources are typically JMS and JDBC resources. You cannot rollback a web service call.